# Left alignment of multiple equations with one label

Tags: align, labels

I am using flalign for left alingment of two equations, but I also want to give them one label for which I found the split environment. But they are not working together.
The question is how to align left two equations but give them one common label?

Comment: `fl` in `flalign` stands for full length not flush left, normally alignment is a document property so `[fleqn]` option to the documentclass or amsmath. "not working together" does not really give any clue as to what you did, or what error message you got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is not yet clear, do you mean one of the following variations of the theme?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \hrule
  \begin{flalign}
    \begin{gathered}
      \text{First equation.}\hfill\\
      \text{Second equation.}
    \end{gathered}
    &&
  \end{flalign}
  \hrule
  \begin{flalign}
    \begin{gathered}
      \text{Bla} \\
      \text{Centered}
    \end{gathered}
    &&
  \end{flalign}
  \hrule
  \begin{flalign}
    \begin{aligned}
      1 + 2 &= 3 \\
      4 &= 2^2 * 2^0
    \end{aligned}
    &&
  \end{flalign}
  \hrule
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Variations with updated information. The first case puts all to the left, the second case is more complicate, it sets the equations in the middle, but the text to the left:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{flalign}
  \begin{aligned}
    \text{or}\quad f &= m \frac{dv}{dt};\\
    \text{or}\quad f &= m \frac{d^2y}{dt^2};
  \end{aligned}
  &&
\end{flalign}
\hrule
\begin{flalign}
  \begin{gathered}
    \rlap{or}\vphantom{\frac{dv}{dt}} \\
    \rlap{or}\vphantom{\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}}
  \end{gathered}
  &&
  \begin{aligned}
    f &= m \frac{dv}{dt};\\
    f &= m \frac{d^2y}{dt^2};
  \end{aligned}
  &&
\end{flalign}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I intended the first example. I am using your code like this which is not working. The error is, Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
    \begin{gathered}
        \text{or} && f &= m \frac{dv}{dt};&\\
        \text{or}  &&f &= m  \frac{d^2y}{dt^2};
    \end{gathered}
    &&
\end{flalign}
\end{document}

Comment: If you want to align the equations additionally, then `aligned` should be used instead of `gathered`. I have updated the answer with two more variants with the text part on left. It remains unclear, where the equations should go.

Comment: I was looking for case 2 here. The only remaining question is the purpose of vphantom here. I removed it and the output was still the same. By the way, that's an incredible amount of help. Thanks!

Comment: @QasimChaudhari The `\vphantom` are needed to get the correct baselines for "or".